# RCP<Epetra_MultiVector> to Epetra_Vector conversion (Trilinos)

Tags: c++, trilinos

I have a `Teuchos::RCP<Epetra_MultiVector> X` made of only 1 column,
and I want to convert this vector into a simple `Epetra_Vector.`
I used the following functions:

```
  const Teuchos::RCP<Epetra_Vector> x_rcp =
    Teuchos::rcpWithEmbeddedObj( (*X)(1), X, false );

  Epetra_Vector* x = x_rcp.getRawPtr();
```

I can compile these functions, but when I try to print out both
`x_rcp` and `x` I do not get any result (files are not written), the code stops
with error:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is convert between a `Teuchos::RCP` to an `Epetra_MultiVector` and an `Epetra_Vector`, you don't need to use any extra Teuchos reference count pointers. You can access an `Epetra_Vector` from an `Epetra_MultiVector` directly using the [() operator](https://trilinos.org/docs/r11.10/packages/epetra/doc/html/classEpetra__MultiVector.html#a9ff1873a78c6fecf7a3188f925689e9c) of `Epetra_MultiVector`, which you've done in your code. You can do the following:

```
Epetra_Vector* x = new Epetra_Vector(*((*X)(0)));
```

(this is assuming you're using zero-indexing; your error may in part be that you accessed (*X)(1) instead of (*X)(0))

You already are using (*X)(1) to get an `Epetra_Vector` pointer; all I've done extra here is dereferenced that to get the `Epetra_Vector` object, and made a copy using the `Epetra_Vector` copy constructor.

This `Epetra_Vector` will be independent of the original `Epetra_MultiVector`.

If you would like, you can also create a `Teuchos::RCP` object using this pointer, and then take the raw pointer from that. This is generally discouraged in `Teuchos::RCP` documentation, however, which states:

> WARNING:: Avoid exposing raw C++ pointers!